# how to draw a rectangle on a canvas with mouse, but see the rectangle while moving the mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

i'm new to WPF, learning by migrating an existing winforms app.

i'm drawing rectangles on a Canvas, which contains an Image.  the rectangles get the X,Y, and Z information from the imported IntPtr object on the Image, which is then analysed as data.

drawing the rectangles is easy enough with Children.Add() and the data capture is working fine, but i can only see the rectangle once it's drawn, so it's hard to know what area you are going to select.  i'd like to see it during the drawing as the mouse moves (like a standard lasso rectangle).  in winforms i used the Paint event, how to do similar in WPF?  i'm using MouseDown and MouseUp events to capture the start and end points of the rectangle

```
        public void MouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e, Canvas evImage)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                startPos = e.GetPosition(evImage);
            evImage.CaptureMouse();
        }

        public void MouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e, Canvas evImage)
        {
            if (Constants.count < 3)
            {
                if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
                    currentPos = e.GetPosition(evImage);

                rec = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle()
                {
                    Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    Name = "rec" + Constants.count.ToString(),
                };

                if (startPos.X < currentPos.X)
                    rec.Width = currentPos.X - startPos.X;
                else
                    rec.Width = startPos.X - currentPos.X;
                if (startPos.Y < currentPos.Y)
                    rec.Height = currentPos.Y - startPos.Y;
                else
                    rec.Height = startPos.Y - currentPos.Y;

                if (rec.Height < 8)
                    rec.Height = 8;
                if (rec.Width < 8)
                    rec.Width = 8;

                if (evImage.Children.Count > Constants.count + 1)
                    evImage.Children.RemoveAt(Constants.count + 1);
                evImage.Children.Insert(Constants.count + 1, rec);
                Canvas.SetLeft(rec, startPos.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(rec, startPos.Y);
                evImage.ReleaseMouseCapture();

                SetRectangleData();
                Constants.count++;
            }
            else
            {
                Constants.count = 0;
                RecMove(e, evImage);
            }
        }
```

XAML - this is my main learning point, i don't know if using the Image in the Canvas is a problem, or if i need to reference something here like the rectangle?

```
<Canvas x:Name="evCanvas" MouseUp="evCanvas_MouseUp" MouseDown="evCanvas_MouseDown" Grid.Column="1" Height="550" Width="626" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,43,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Image x:Name="evImage" Height="550" Width="626" MouseMove="evImage_MouseMove" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Create the rectangle on MouseDown and update it's size on MouseMove.

Comment: wow, thanks mate that was easy.  appreciate your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set Left and Top to the minimum x and y and width to max-x and height max-y.

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp" Background="Transparent" />
```

Then doing as follows:

```
private Point startPoint;
private Rectangle rect;

private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

    rect = new Rectangle
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
        StrokeThickness = 2
    };
    Canvas.SetLeft(rect,startPoint.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect,startPoint.Y);
    canvas.Children.Add(rect);
}

private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released || rect == null)
        return;

    var pos = e.GetPosition(canvas);

    var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
    var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);

    var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
    var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;

    rect.Width = w;
    rect.Height = h;

    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);
}

private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    rect = null;
}
```